# Enable the Enhanced Profile User Interface in a new scratch org

Tags: configuration, scratch-org-definition-file

Every time I create a new Scratch Org, it uses the old profile user interface. Is there a scratch org definition file config setting I can toggle so that the [Enhanced Profile User Interface](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_about_enhanced_ui.htm&type=5) is enabled in the Org? Perusing the Scratch Org Features, one didn't jump out at me -- but perhaps I missed it?

Failing a config setting, is there a way to toggle this setting via sfdx force:data:tree:import?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a setting available:

```json
"settings": {
    "userManagementSettings": {
        "enableNewProfileUI": true
    }
}
```